# How to call Pinch and Zoom class on am ImageView?

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie to android development. Here I am trying to add pinch and zoom an image in my image view. The image is loaded on an activity called FullScreenView

Here is my FullScreenView.java file

```
public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = FullScreenViewActivity.class
            .getSimpleName();
    public static final String TAG_SEL_IMAGE = "selectedImage";
    private Wallpaper selectedPhoto;
    private ImageView fullImageView;
    private LinearLayout llSetWallpaper, llDownloadWallpaper,btShare;
    private Utils utils;
    private ProgressBar pbLoader;

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;



    // Picasa JSON response node keys
    private static final String TAG_ENTRY = "entry",
            TAG_MEDIA_GROUP = "media$group",
            TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT = "media$content", TAG_IMG_URL = "url",
            TAG_IMG_WIDTH = "width", TAG_IMG_HEIGHT = "height";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image);

        //add code
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        requestNewInterstitial();



        fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFullscreen);
        llSetWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSetWallpaper);
        llDownloadWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llDownloadWallpaper);
        btShare = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btShare);
        pbLoader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoader);

        // hide the action bar in fullscreen mode
        getActionBar().hide();

        utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

        // layout click listeners
        llSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
        btShare.setOnClickListener(this);

        // setting layout buttons alpha/opacity
        llSetWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);
        llDownloadWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);
        btShare.getBackground().setAlpha(70);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        selectedPhoto = (Wallpaper) i.getSerializableExtra(TAG_SEL_IMAGE);

        // check for selected photo null
        if (selectedPhoto != null) {

            // fetch photo full resolution image by making another json request
            fetchFullResolutionImage();


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }







    }

    private void requestNewInterstitial()
    {

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("PFSW5H65PRTS9TTO")
                .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);





    }

    /**
     * Fetching image fullresolution json
     * */
    private void fetchFullResolutionImage() {
        String url = selectedPhoto.getPhotoJson();

        // show loader before making request
        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llSetWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // volley's json obj request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                "Image full resolution json: "
                                        + response.toString());
                        try {
                            // Parsing the json response
                            JSONObject entry = response
                                    .getJSONObject(TAG_ENTRY);

                            JSONArray mediacontentArry = entry.getJSONObject(
                                    TAG_MEDIA_GROUP).getJSONArray(
                                    TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT);

                            JSONObject mediaObj = (JSONObject) mediacontentArry
                                    .get(0);

                            final String fullResolutionUrl = mediaObj
                                    .getString(TAG_IMG_URL);

                            // image full resolution widht and height
                            final int width = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_WIDTH);
                            final int height = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_HEIGHT);

                            Log.d(TAG, "Full resolution image. url: "
                                    + fullResolutionUrl + ", w: " + width
                                    + ", h: " + height);

                            ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController
                                    .getInstance().getImageLoader();

                            // We download image into ImageView instead of
                            // NetworkImageView to have callback methods
                            // Currently NetworkImageView doesn't have callback
                            // methods

                            imageLoader.get(fullResolutionUrl,
                                    new ImageListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onErrorResponse(
                                                VolleyError arg0) {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(
                                                ImageContainer response,
                                                boolean arg1) {
                                            if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                                                // load bitmap into imageview
                                                fullImageView
                                                        .setImageBitmap(response
                                                                .getBitmap());
                                                adjustImageAspect(width, height);


                                                // hide loader and show set &
                                                // download buttons
                                                pbLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                llSetWallpaper
                                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                llDownloadWallpaper
                                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                                btShare
                                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        // unable to fetch wallpapers
                        // either google username is wrong or
                        // devices doesn't have internet connection
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

        // Remove the url from cache
        AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);

        // Disable the cache for this url, so that it always fetches updated
        // json
        jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

    }

    /**
     * Adjusting the image aspect ration to scroll horizontally, Image height
     * will be screen height, width will be calculated respected to height
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void adjustImageAspect(int bWidth, int bHeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT , LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        if (bWidth == 0 || bHeight == 0)
            return;

        int sHeight = 0;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            sHeight = size.y;
        } else {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            sHeight = display.getHeight();
        }

        int new_width = (int) Math.floor((double) bWidth * (double) sHeight
                / (double) bHeight);
        params.width = new_width;
        params.height = sHeight;

        Log.d(TAG, "Fullscreen image new dimensions: w = " + new_width
                + ", h = " + sHeight);

        //fullImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
       // fullImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        fullImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);


    }

    /**
     * View click listener
     * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } //else
        //{
           // beginPlayingGame();
       // }


        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fullImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
        File cache = getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir();
        File sharefile = new File(cache, "toshare.png");
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(sharefile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }



        switch (v.getId()) {
        // button Download Wallpaper tapped
        case R.id.llDownloadWallpaper:
            utils.saveImageToSDCard(bitmap);

            break;
        // button Set As Wallpaper tapped
        case R.id.llSetWallpaper:
            utils.setAsWallpaper(bitmap);
            break;


            case R.id.btShare:
                Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/*");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + sharefile));
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share photo"));
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

I also create the class for bringing pinch and zoom facility to this.

ZoomableImageView.java

```
public class ZoomableImageView extends View {
   //Code goes here
}
```

How to call this ZoomableImageView  java class file to FullScreenViewActivity so that,when i pinch and zoom, it get works...

Comment: Note that there are plenty of existing widgets that offer gesture-based zooming of images, such as the ones listed at http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=pinch.

Comment: Have you tried photo view attacher for android studio? https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView